# Can't take value of a macro: #'clojure.core/case

Tags: clojure

I am creating a function within a function in Clojure, to simulate Java's objects concept where my function person acts like a constructor. (Just to wrap my head around using this concept in Clojure.)

```
(defn person [name age]
  (def p (fn [args & age]
    case args
     :set-name (person (first args) age)
     :set-age (person age)
    ;; :get-name (person (first args))
    ;; :get-age ()
)))
```

But I am getting the following error :

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro: #'clojure.core/case, compiling:(null:2:8)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you mean that the `person` function should return a new function (your `p`), or do you want to define the inner function `p` and use it in the body of `person`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You (almost always) shouldn't use a `def` inside another `def` or `defn`.  Using `def` is a global declaration and it should (nearly) always stand alone in the source file.

See [Clojure for the Brave & True](https://www.braveclojure.com/) for an intro online, or many good books like `Getting Clojure`.

2. You forgot the parens around `case`:

Example:

```
(case args ...)
```

3. Using `case` is really a special function designed primarily for Java object interop, and comes with some serious limitations (aka "optimizations").  It is nearly always better IMHO to use `cond`.

Example:

```
(cond
  (= :set-name args)   (person (first args) age)
  (= :set-age  args)   (person age)
  ...)
```

---

### Update

One of the problems with `case` is that it must be [a compile-time literal](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/case).  However, this is not obvious and there is no warning if you try to use something that doesn't fit the definition.  Then, you just get a silent failure.  This example looks like it should return `"my vec"`, but it fails & returns `"default"`:

```
; "The test-constants are not evaluated.  They must be compile-time
; literals, and need not be quoted." 
(let [myvec [1 2]]
  (case myvec
    []             "empty vec"
    (vec '(1 2))   "my vec"
    "default"))
;=> "default"
```

So using `case` leaves a booby-trap ready to break your code without warning.

Comment: I'm not sure I can agree with the third point. Their use of `case` here seems entirely appropriate. `case` does, afaik, constant time dispatch, while `cond` requires sequential condition checks. I can't see why `cond` would be preferred here.

Comment: The lack of warnings is unfortunate, but the behavior is well documented. Considering it's the right tool for the job here, I'm don't think the potential for misuse is enough to discourage its use. A warning about the behavior would probably be more appropriate.